# C Structure variable access

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I would like some help accessing the arrays in my struct. My program compiles without any errors, but stalls when I try to change some values in my struct. I'm stumped as to what the problem is, and would greatly appreciate some assistance.

Global struct declaration:

```
typedef struct Data {
    float timestamp[array_length];
    float azimuth[array_length];
    float distance[array_length];
    float signal_strength[array_length];
} Datain;

Datain *dataptr;
```

This is were I try to initialize the arrays to what I would like them to be:

```
for (i = 0; i <  array_length; i++)
{
    dataptr->timestamp[i]=-100;
    dataptr->distance[i]=-100;
    dataptr->azimuth[i]=-100;
    dataptr->signal_strength[i]=-100;
}
```

Let me know what you think

Comment: Where do you allocate the memory for dataptr?  Also what do you mean by “stalls”?

Comment: Not enough information to help. Please write a [mcve].

Comment: i also suspect your data shape is wrong. I think you want an array of struct, each struct has one of timestamp, distance, azimuth, signal_strength.

Comment: @zzxyz By stalls I mean the console freezes or gets stuck in a loop, and nothing is shown. Memory allocation was the issue. Thanks for the help

Comment: please post a [mcve] so we can debug the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dataptr` is an uninitialized pointer, it's pointing to nowhere. You have to
allocate memory for it:

```
dataptr = malloc(sizeof *dataptr); // or malloc(size * sizeof *dataptr)
                                   // for allocating size Datain objects
if(dataptr == NULL)
{
    // error handling
    // do not continue
}

for(i=0;i<array_length;i++)
{
    dataptr->timestamp[i]=-100;
    dataptr->distance[i]=-100;
    dataptr->azimuth[i]=-100;
    dataptr->signal_strength[i]=-100;
}

/*
   or if you do the malloc(size * sizeof *dataptr)

for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
    for(size_t j = 0; j < array_length; ++j)
    {
        dataptr[i].timestamp[j]=-100;
        dataptr[i].distance[j]=-100;
        dataptr[i].azimuth[j]=-100;
        dataptr[i].signal_strength[j]=-100;
    }
}
*/
```

and later you don't have to forget to free the memory with

```
free(dataptr);
```

And if `dataptr` is meant to be a single object, then you don't need to declare
it as a pointer:

```
Datain dataptr; // no * here
```

then later in a function

```
for(i=0;i<array_length;i++)
{
    dataptr.timestamp[i]=-100;
    dataptr.distance[i]=-100;
    dataptr.azimuth[i]=-100;
    dataptr.signal_strength[i]=-100;
}
```

and here you don't need to free the memory.

Comment: This was it! Thank you very much. I figured the solution was some simple ID10T error